# Running the Selenium Web Driver execution at low speed

Tags: junit

How to run the `Selenium WebDriver`  at slow speed by using `Junit` framework.

tried using

```
wait( );
```

but can't succeed.

can I use `wait();` or Is there any other method?

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver used to have a `#setSpeed()`-method, but it seems to have been removed.

You should be able to wrap your WebDriver in a `EventFiringWebDriver` and do a `Thread.sleep()` for the events you want to slow down.

```
    EventFiringWebDriver eventFiringWebDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(yourWebDriver);
    eventFiringWebDriver.register(new WebDriverEventListener() {
        // Implement bunch of methods
    }
```

Using Thread.sleep() seems like a bit of a hack to me though. Are there no other ways of achieving your goal other than slowing down your tests?

There are also tools that lets you emulate low-bandwidth (slow) network connections. Running your Selenium-test through these should also decrease your speed.

[ip_relay](http://www.stewart.com.au/ip_relay/) proxies your connection:

```
    $ iprelay -b2500 8000:localhost:80
```

`http://localhost:8000` will proxy your connection to `http://localhost:80` and slow it down.

Traffic Control (`tc`) lets you [do something similiar](http://blogs.kde.org/node/1878).